# Don't know which project to create inside Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new with developing web application with Java Spring Framework inside Spring Tool Suite IDE. When start a new project there are so many kinds of project such as Spring Project, Simple Spring Utility Project, Spring VMC Template Project, Spring Roo Project, Static Web Project, Dynamic Web Project and Maven Project. I do not know which project I should select? Can someone explain me, please?

Comment: This seems too broad.

Comment: "Import Spring Getting Started Content" will open a wizard where you can select one of the Spring Guides and have that created with initial and/or complete code

Answer (score 6):

I would choose none of the above.

If you have a recent version of STS (since 3.4 I think)  there is also an "Import Spring Getting Started Content" (clue in the name: if you are getting started this is a good place to look, and all the guides are online at https://spring.io/guides). If you are studying the guides then this is the best place to start.

You also get a "Spring Starter Project" option directly in the "New" menu. If you want a minimal project with enough code to run but no actual business logic, then this is the best place to start. It's what you would use to create the code in the guides mostly.

The other options (including all those listed in the original post) are unofficially deprecated, and not particularly well maintained or modern.

Comment: Isn't the most modern way nowadays called Spring Boot or do some of the starter projects pull it in automatically?

Comment: @anttix I believe that is what the Spring Starter Project is, although I prefer to start a project outside of STS using Yeoman, use Gradle to generate the .project, then import it.

Comment: @CodeChimp AFAIK boot is supposed to use Gradle as it's build system. Will the starter generate a gradle project? I don't have a Spring 4 based STS at hand :(

Comment: In my case, I have always used Yeoman to generate the initial project folder for Spring Boot, but I do believe it will.  Also, I don't believe Spring Boot forces you to use Gradle, but rather that is the "default" with Maven as an option.  At least, that's what my fuzzy brain tells me.

Answer (score 0):

As an absolute beginner, I would read up on Spring Roo and then pick either Spring MVC or Spring Roo project depending on whether I liked Roo or not.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between these two MVC and ROO?

Comment: One uses Roo, the other one does not, please visit Spring Roo homepage to find out what Roo is and why you might want to use it.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Comment: Roo is sort of like Spring Boot beta, except it does more code-gen and boilerplate gen and less auto-configuring.  From the speed of the last few updates to Roo, it looks like it might be a dying project.  I would opt for Spring Boot over Roo, as it looks like it has a lot of steam behind it ATM.  If you really wanted to "learn", then Roo is somewhat nice because you can see what it's doing, but you would need to understand that the AOP nature of Roo is something most projects don't really do quite so much.

Comment: Currently Roo is a better way to learn the entire technology stack. Boot example projects cover the basics but not to the depth of Roo eg. full security, JPA etc setup in less than 5 minutes. It is true that Roo is falling out of favor though ...

Comment: How about Spring MVC Template Project and Maven Project inside STS IDE? Which one should I choose and why?

Comment: So my suggestion would be to prototype with Roo and build with Boot once you understand how ;) Hopefully boot will evolve to the point where we don't need Roo.

Comment: You can choose a Maven project, but that means you need to add all Spring dependencies manually. This is like a plain New Java Project but with Maven set up as a build tool.

Comment: @anttix, and what is the reason that I should not choose Spring MVC Template Project, but choose Maven project instead?

Comment: If you are building something that should be built with Maven and possibly does not depend on Spring. E.g. a library. Or maybe you are not happy how the other project sets itself up so you start with bare bones. I suggest you also read up on what build tools are available for Java. e.g. what is ant, maven, gradle etc. This is an opinionated choice and you should grow an opinion ;)